# Using an iPhone 5 (Verizon version) in Europe and India?

Tags: sim, iphone, cellular-carriers, cdma

I am going to try and consolidate all of the questions I have here:

1. Can I use the Verizon iPhone5 with a GSM carrier in Europe (Vodafone) and in India (Airtel or Aircel) with both calling and cellular data working properly?
2. Question 1 extended: Could I use it on the GSM carriers whilst on a 2 yr contract with Verizon? (The way I understand, it does come unlocked??)
3. On ending my contract will I be able to pop in a t-mobile sim and use it in the US?

Please advise

Comment: We try not to combine multiple questions into one here, for future reference.

Comment: @Samuel I apologize. The only reason I consolidated was due to how closely the questions tied into each other.

Comment: I think it's fine with one and two, but three would be a separate question. It's fine here, since you've already gotten an answer, but it's something to keep in mind for the future: it makes answering questions so much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes.
2. Yes.
3. Yes.

Only quirk is you won’t get LTE data on networks other than Verizon, especially Airtel and Aircel, as Asian carriers use different bands. You are *probably* gonna get LTE in Europe, and that too most likely on CDMA networks, but you will have to check with the carrier. I really hate this fragmentation.

Comment: Thanks! I share your sentiments on that last line of yours. I am assuming then, that LTE is the only global issue. I would still be able to use 3G or HSPA globally right?

Comment: Yes, 3G on CDMA and GSM. Probably 3.5G or 3G+ or 4G (whatever) too, but that too is fragmented, though less than LTE.

Comment: Thanks again! Here is something I found:  http://www.engadget.com/2012/09/21/verizon-iphone-5-unlocked-att-t-mobile-video/

Comment: Yeah, that’s awesome too. I feel that the Verizon phone is the true “global” phone. It at least supports very basic standards like EDGE all over the world.

Comment: I would buy the Verizon version in a heart beat, but the only let down is the lack of simultaneous voice and data on LTE :(

Comment: Yeah that’s a problem, but LTE on CDMA simply doesn’t support it without a third (!!) antenna.

Comment: Tough luck huh!